# I am using sharepoint with C#. While saving data in sharepoint list it is getting saved but while inserting attachment it is giving exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am saving form data with attachments. Form data is saving in list properly but while updating attachment it is giving exception of
"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
at Skoda_DCMS.DAL.IDCardDAL.d__12.MoveNext() in D:\07-July-2023\eForms_Skoda_UAT_CHECK\eForms_Skoda\Skoda_DCMS\DAL\IDCardDAL.cs:line 440.

But Im using another person's login then it is saving properly.Code for uploading attachment is

```
   if (file != null)
            {
                int attachmentID = RowId;

                string path = file.FileName;
                path = path.Replace(" ", "");
                string FileName = path;

                List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                ListItem itemAttach = docs.GetItemById(attachmentID);

                var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();

                attInfo.FileName = FileName;

                byte[] fileData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }

                attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);

                Attachment att = itemAttach.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo); //Add to File

                _context.Load(att);
                _context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

I have checked the permissions of the list setting in SharePoint.

Comment: Why you think your code will help given that this seems to be a permission proble, not a code issue?

Comment: Can you manually add attachments to the said list via the GUI/browser using your account? If so then you can rule out a permissions issue otherwise check and double check your permissions.

Comment: No, This is used by the user, and we can not upload the attachments from GUI/browser. This issue is raised for specific users only.